# Xpages - Exception occurred calling method NotesView.getNextDocument(lotus.domino.local.Document) null

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs, ssjs

I'm getting the above error.
Is there a way I can check if next document is null?
Below is my code:

```
var vec:NotesView = database.getView("QueryNotes");
var queryColl:NotesDocumentCollection =   vec.getAllDocumentsByKey(ProjectUNID,true);
if(queryColl.getCount() > 0){
var queryDoc1:NotesDocument = queryColl.getFirstDocument();
while (queryDoc1 != null) {
    if(!queryDoc1.hasItem("QueryEndDate")){
        queryDoc1.appendItemValue("QueryEndDate", session.createDateTime(@Now()));

        var tmpdoc = vec.getNextDocument(queryDoc1); //error when next is null, or does not exist
        queryDoc1.recycle();
        queryDoc1 = tmpdoc;
      }
   }
}
```

There should be a way of checking, a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446515/xpages-typeerror-exception-at-view-getnextdocumentcurdoc) on stackoverflow did not answer the question.

Looking forward to your response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling getNextDocument() on the `vec` variable (which is a view object and doesn't have that method). You should use the `queryColl` variable instead.

Comment: That's the one problem. Another one is dealing with iteration (getNext, recycle...) inside that if statement...